# How css menu list can be genrated for a repeater with in repeater bounded by database?

Tags: asp.net, css, repeater

I want my menu list to be like this

[image]

even more beautiful

currently i have coded like this to bind my repeater to database and fetch menu from it

```
<div id="main" class="shell">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul class="categories" id="categoryheader">
                <li id="categoryItem">
                    <h4>Categories</h4>
                    <ul class="categories" id="categorylist">
            <asp:Repeater ID="repCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperCategories" runat="server"><%#Eval("CategoryName")%></asp:HyperLink>
                                <ul class="subcategories" id="subcategorylist">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repsubcategory" runat="server">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ul>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperSubCategories" runat="server"><%#Eval("SubCategoryName")%></asp:HyperLink>                                       
                                            </li>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <h4>Company</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="repCompany" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperCompany" runat="server"><%#Eval("CompanyName")%></asp:HyperLink>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I used repeater within repeater. and will add one more subcategory repeater to it. 
Please help me to solve this Please

Comment: Use one of the jQuery plugin for menu. You can find one here http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/